# Do bachelor's and master's degrees have to be the same in order to apply for a doctorate?

Tags: phd, europe, australia, new-zealand

I got my bachelors degree in the field of wood and paper science engineering and got my masters degree in the field of industrial engineering. I have more than 15 years of experience in the field of industrial engineering (planning, production planning, mathematical modeling, and multi criteria decision making). Besides, I have 8 years of research experience in the same field with 15 research projects and papers published in international journals with IF between 1.945 to 5.467. I am wondering, is it possible to apply for a PhD in industrial engineering in Europe, Australia, and New Zealand? Or do my bachelors degree and masters degree have to be the same in order to apply for a PhD position?
I know there are many criteria and each university has their own rules and regulation, but can you give me an answer in general?

Comment: Those two fields are a lot closer together than many combinations. That background should be fine in principle. But, as you say, you need to discuss with the particular universities you are interested in applying to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment JenB

Answer (score 5):

**No**, you do not need to have bachelor’s and master’s degrees in the same field in order to apply for a doctorate. Each university will have its own rules and admission criteria, but I have not ever seen it be a requirement.

Some universities will only admit students to the doctorate level if they have obtained a master’s in the same field at the same university as the doctorate, but even this is not always the case.

Comment: I suggest you mention your experience in a least one of the named places. I know what you say would be true in US, but I have no way to judge elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for other countries. In the US, you can directly apply to a Ph.D. program without having a master's degree. I believe your really good experience can compensate a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Thank you.